# Does MySQL store the secondary indexes and the clustered index in same .ibd file?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

In a file-per-table tablespace, are the secondary indexes stored in the same `.ibd` file as the clustered index?

Comment: Why should it matter?  Do _not_ copy a .ibd file to somewhere else; it is likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces.html has this answer:

> A file-per-table tablespace contains data and indexes for a single InnoDB table, and is stored on the file system in a single data file.